# How to write date to a text file only once?

Tags: java

I successfully created a file and wrote a date, but when I run my application a file overwrites current date everytime.

What I want to do:

1. Create a file in the project directory when application run the first time
2. Write the current date to a file
3. If I run the program again and there is text(date) then read the current date and show it `System.out.println()`.

**What is wrong in my code**?

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

Date currentDate = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
String date = dateFormat.format(currentDate);

File file = new File("outTest.txt");
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);


FileReader fr = new FileReader("outTest.txt");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
String str;

if (file.length() == 0) {

      writer.write(date);
      writer.flush();
      writer.close();

}
else if(file.length() > 0) {

  while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(str + "\n");
  }
  br.close();

}

}

}
```

Comment: You're executing `FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);` unconditionally. That will create a new, zero-length file regardless of whether there was a file present before.

Comment: Add a check for the file existence and create the writer only if the file does not exists

Comment: Is there a reason you are using the old file IO framework instead of NIO? Similar for the date API, why not using the new modern `java.time`? That whole code could be redone into 3-5 lines using the new APIs.

Comment: @Zabuza I'm a newbee in programming and I don't know what is old and what is new

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Java NIO:

```
LocalDateTime currentDate = LocalDateTime.now();
String date = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm").format(currentDate);

Path file = Paths.get("outTest.txt");

if (!Files.exists(file) || Files.size(file) == 0) {
    Files.write(file, List.of(date));
}

Files.lines(file).forEach(System.out::println);
```

**EDIT:** `java.time` and UTF-8 charset used.

**EDIT 2:** explicit charset parameter is not necessary as NIO uses UTF-8 per default

Answer (score 0):

Check if the file [exists](https://alvinalexander.com/java/java-file-exists-directory-exists) and then print:

```
// test to see if a file exists
File file = new File("filename-date.txt");
exists = file.exists();
if (file.exists() && file.isFile())
{
  System.out.println("File exists. Here is the name: " + file.getName());
}
```